# Will there be compatibility problems for crankset and bottom bracket for vintage motobecane?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, compatibility, vintage

Most concerned about compatibility of bottom bracket/crank area. Not sure of model and year, any ideas? Some specs...1020 tubes,forks and stays, weinmann 610/vanqueur 999                                              brakes, SR headset,suntour derailleaurs....obviously some rebuilding done, but does say something about compatibility issues.     Thanks!!! Blueskynolimit

ps can someone tell me how to "attach" photos?

Comment: **PHOTOS** Take a photo and get it to your computer.  Hit the [edit] link straight below your question.  Then use the 6th button from the left (icon of two mountain peaks in a box with a sun or moon above)   Follow the wizard and it should help.  As a low-rep user you can add up to two photos, and each should be under 2 megabytes in size.

Answer (score 2):

Old Motobecanes are all over the place with BB threads. There are large numbers of them each with French, ISO/English, and Swiss. (Swiss may seem odd, but the deal with it is that it's the same 35x1 thread as French but with a left-threaded drive side cup, to prevent loosening. So it's kind of a natural progression from French, although I don't know the exact history with Motobecane using it.) Many but not all BBs have their thread type inscribed on the outside of the cup. I'm sure there's also a heavy correlation with where in the world the bike was originally sold - i.e. if it was for the domestic market it's probably not ISO.